# Convert a table with unknown structure into Key/Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, key-value

The report data we receive from analysts come in Table format with arbitrary structure. All we know is that each row has a `CustomerId` column. But the others, we do not know and can vary every time.

The destination system that receives this data only does in Key/Value format so we have to convert the report tables into Key/Value.

So, if for instance, the source report table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleSourceTable](
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Column1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NULL,
    [Column3] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleSourceTable] ([CustomerId], [Column1], [Column2], [Column3]) VALUES (1, N'aaa', 123, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleSourceTable] ([CustomerId], [Column1], [Column2], [Column3]) VALUES (2, N'bbb', 456, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

[image]

We would like this data to be converted into the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable](
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Attribute] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'Column1', N'aaa')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'Column2', N'123')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'Column3', N'2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Column1', N'bbb')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Column2', N'456')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SampleDestinationTable] ([CustomerId], [Attribute], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Column3', N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000')
GO
```

[image]

The challenge here, however, is that the source report table does not have a fixed structure.

At first, I thought about going through every row using a cursor and then using a nested cursor go through all the columns in that row. But apparently, [there is no way of processing a row with an unknown structure using cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036488/process-a-row-with-unknown-structure-in-a-cursor). So for now, I am wondering if this is possible using PIVOT/UNPIVOT. But then again, I think they also require the column list.

I am running SQL Server 2017.

How do I do transform the data with an unknown structure?

Comment: You want the `CREATE TABLE` query, the `INSERT` query, or both?

Comment: That destination seems like a bad idea; you're storing a `varchar(3)`, an `int`, and a `datetime` in the same column. `varchar` isn't a one size fits all data type.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis neither, I want to convert the table in the first picture to the one in the second.

Comment: That's more like "both"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to generate a dynamic statement using information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

-- Dynamic part 
SELECT 
    @stm = STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(
            N' UNION ALL SELECT CustomerID, ''', 
            [COLUMN_NAME],
            N''' AS [Attribute], CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ',
            QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]),
            CASE 
                WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' THEN N', 121'
                -- Add additional conversion rules for other data types
                ELSE N''
            END,
            N') AS [Value]', 
            N' FROM [SampleSourceTable]'
        )
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'SampleSourceTable') AND (COLUMN_NAME <> 'CustomerId')
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 11, N'')

-- Whole statement and execution
SET @stm = @stm + N'ORDER BY CustomerID'
PRINT @stm 
EXEC (@stm)
```

Output:

```
CustomerID  Attribute   Value
1           Column1     aaa       
1           Column2     123
1           Column3     2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           Column3     2018-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           Column2     456
2           Column1     bbb
```

Comment: This seems to work beautifully.  Could you elaborate a little on `-- Add additional conversion rules for other data types`? What other data types should be specifically covered here?

Comment: @disasterkid Other `date/time` data types  - `date`, `datetime2` for example. Of course, if you have such columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you opened a second question, I just placed an answer at your first...

So I will use this place to provide the same technique as my other answer, but without any need of dynamically created SQL. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =(SELECT TOP 10 o.object_id,o.* FROM sys.objects o FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL);

SELECT r.value('*[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RowID
        ,c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnKey
        ,c.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/row') A(r)
CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('*[position()>1]') B(c);
```

The first column of the set will be returned as *RowID*. If this is not correct, you can force this by doing the same as I've done above to force the `o.object_id` in the first place. All Columns of your result will be returned as EAV.

Part of the result

```
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| RowID | ColumnKey           | ColumnValue             |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | name                | sysrscols               |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | object_id           | 3                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | principal_id        | NULL                    |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | schema_id           | 4                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | parent_object_id    | 0                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | type                | S                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | type_desc           | SYSTEM_TABLE            |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | create_date         | 2017-08-22T19:38:02.860 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | modify_date         | 2017-08-22T19:38:02.867 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | is_ms_shipped       | 1                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | is_published        | 0                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3     | is_schema_published | 0                       |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 5     | name                | sysrowsets              |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| ... more rows ...
```